# Limiting the area in which a jqueryui sortable item can be dropped

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have an 'ul' of elements, the last 'li' of which is to create new elements.
The ul is sortable thanks to jqueryui sortable() and I have excluded the last 'li' element from the $('ul').sortable() so that the element is not draggable. However, other items from the list can be dropped under this last li element. I want to prevent this. Is there any way to limit where can the items be dropped?

Simple concept HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="list-element">potato</li>
    <li class="list-element">tomato</li>
    <li class="list-element">banana</li>
    <li class="list-element">pistacchio</li>
    <li class="new-element">new product</li>
</ul>
```

and .js:

```
$('ul').sortable();
$("ul").disableSelection();
$('ul').sortable({ cancel: '.new-element' });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s4yjpoaL/

As you can see all the items can be dragged under the .new-element li. Is there any way to limit the draggability up to right before the last li element?

PS: I know it'd be way easier to have the last element outside the ul, but that's not the point here :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this by specifying the `items` of the sort to be the other `li` items.

http://jsfiddle.net/s4yjpoaL/2/

```
$('ul').sortable({
    items: ".list-element",
    cancel: ".new-element",
});
```

This disables the drop zone for the last element in addition to making it unsortable.

Comment: works like a charm, thanks! It's funny because in my original code I didn't have a class for the list elems and tried something like //items : ':not(.new-element)', which didn't work properly :P I'll accept as soon as SO lets me!